# Oracle with java program

Tags: java, oracle, file

I have a java program compiled in Oracle 10g.
The program in java what it does is move a file from one directory to another directory.

an example of code java:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED PRENSA."MoveFile" as 
import java.io.File;

public class MoveFile
{
    public static void getList(String directory )

    {
        try{

           File smfile =new File( directory );
            System.out.println( directory );
            System.out.println( smfile.getName() );            
           if(smfile.renameTo(new File("c:\\simedia_xml\\Procesados" + smfile.getName()))){            

            System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
           }else{
            System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
           }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}
```

the java program received a name of the file, example hola.xml from oracle.
the permissions:

```
 BEGIN
    dbms_java.grant_permission( 'PRENSA','SYS:java.io.FilePermission','c:\\simedia_xml\\Procesados\\hola.xml','read,write' );
END;
```

But at the time of running the script, it gives me the error that you can not rename the file, as I am missing permissions to write it.

Have some idea of what permissions I have to give so that the java write the file to me in the directory that I command as a parameter.

Comment: Please show the COMPLETE error message.

Answer (score 0):

the permisions:

dbms_java.grant_permission( 'PRENSA','SYS:java.io.FilePermission','c:\simedia_xml\Procesados\*','read,write' );

add * to all files in this folder is the solution.